# Fullcalendar Error in IE9: script438 object doesn't support property or method 'fullcalendar' IE9

Tags: heroku, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar V1.6.4 with jquery v1.10.2. It is working fine with IE9 in Local development server. But it is giving error "**script438 object doesn't support property or method 'fullcalendar**'" in production server (Heroku) with IE9. Error is only in IE9, it is workin fine in IE10 and IE11 in production server (Heroku).
Any help in this regard is appreciated